# Split a Description Column to 3 Columns, T-SQL / SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, string, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need to split a `nvarchar(100)` column into three `nvarchar(28)` columns without a known delimiter and without breaking mid-word.  I am thinking that I would need to find the space that is near the 28th character, measure length and position of the word just before that space and decide weather the delimiter should be before or after that word.  Then, again for the 3rd column. 
From:

```
Col
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Royal Mission Open Hutch with 4-Arch Doors, Plain Glass (with Glass Shelves Standard)
```

To:

```
Col1                      Col2                      Col3
------------------------  ------------------------- --------------------------
Royal Mission Open Hutch  4-Arch Doors, Plain Glass (with Glass Shelves Standa
```

Any Ideas? 
Thanks nab

I am using SQL 2008

Comment: 3 * 28 = 84. You may have a problem.

Comment: Are you trying to split plaintext into equally sized blocks to accomodate transfer to some kind of legacy system? Are you planning to discard anything that won't fit in the 3 varchar(28) columns?

Comment: Sample data and expected output would be really helpful to understand the question.

Comment: Yes.  Sorry, I should have stated that is was for import to an old system. Luckily, most source text is less then 90

Comment: google `sql server word wrap`

Comment: Sample:
Royal Mission Open Hutch with 4-Arch Doors, Plain Glass (with Glass Shelves Standard)

Comment: Please update the question instead.

Comment: Royal Mission Open Hutch with<break>4-Arch Doors, Plain Glass (with <Break>Glass Shelves Standard)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using CROSS APPLYs, you could try something like this:

```
WITH data (col) AS (
  SELECT CAST('Royal Mission Open Hutch with 4-Arch Doors, Plain Glass (with Glass Shelves Standard)' AS nvarchar(100))
)
SELECT
  col1, col2, col3
FROM data
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT
    NULLIF(30 - CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(LEFT(col, 29))), 0)
) AS x1 (first_space_pos)
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT
    LEFT(col, ISNULL(first_space_pos, 28)),
    LTRIM(NULLIF(SUBSTRING(col, ISNULL(first_space_pos, 29), 999), ''))
) AS x2 (col1, col23)
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT
    NULLIF(30 - CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(LEFT(col23, 29))), 0)
) AS x3 (second_space_pos)
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT
    LEFT(col23, ISNULL(second_space_pos, 28)),
    LTRIM(NULLIF(SUBSTRING(col23, ISNULL(second_space_pos, 29), 28), ''))
) AS x4 (col2, col3)
;
```

The first CROSS APPLY searches for the last space in the first 29 characters of the big column, and the second one uses the found position to produce the first smaller column, `col1` and return the rest of the string as `col23`.

The next two CROSS APPLYs do perform the same manipulations on `col23`, thus producing `col2` and `col3`. The only difference is, the last CROSS APPLY puts into `col3` at most 28 characters rather than all the remaining ones.

The hardcoded values like `28`, `29` and `30` could be parametrised, but I'll leave that part of the job to you.

You can try this query [at SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/2683).

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. THANKS!  I was thinking along the same lines but couldn't get it from my brain to a working script. I am testing with all of my data and the hardcoded values seem to work.